# why won't my <div> resize with javascript when I tell it to?

Tags: javascript, css, dhtml

I have a `<div>` element that contains a table, which I want to resize to the maximum viewport height - 70 px. The reason is that I want the header to stay in one place, and the table to scroll independantly. I can't use iframes for that, since there is complicated javascript interacting with the table. I therefore have to use a `<div>` and set it's overflow value to scroll. My problem is that the container wont resize when I tell it to. The container looks like this:

```
<div class="tableContainer" id="tblCont">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="mainTbl" class="mainTable">
    <tr class="row_a" id="1">
      <td>id: 1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The CSS for my tableContainer class is as follow:

```
.tableContainer
{
    overflow: scroll;
    /*height: 400px;  -- this was just to see if the concept works - and this seems to work fine */
}
```

Lastly, here is the javascript that is supposed to set the height of the table container:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tbc = document.getElementById("tblCont");
    var h = Math.round((window.innerHeight)-(70))+"px";
    tbc.style.height = h;
</script>
```

I even tried setting a fixed height with

`tbc.style.height = "50px";`

but that also does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your script is being called before your DOM elements exist.  You need to call your script with an onload event handler, and put your script in a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setHeight() {
        var tbc = document.getElementById("tblCont");
        var h = Math.round((window.innerHeight)-(70))+"px";
        tbc.style.height = h;
    }
</script>

<body onload="setHeight()">
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the javascript gets excecuted. I wrapped it inside an init function and it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .tableContainer
            {
                overflow: scroll;
                /*height: 400px;  -- this was just to see if the concept works - and this seems to work fine */
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init()
            {
                var tbc = document.getElementById("tblCont");
                var h = Math.round((window.innerHeight)-(70))+"px";

                document.getElementById('test').onclick = function()
                {
                    tbc.style.width = "40px";
                }
            }

            window.onload = init;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="test" type="button" value="test" />
        </form>

        <div class="tableContainer" id="tblCont">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="mainTbl" class="mainTable">
            <tr class="row_a" id="1">
              <td>id: 1</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, it executes, but if you trace it through a debugger like firebug, you will see that it gets called before the div exists, and therefore fails with a "tbc is null" exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try two things:

First, if you didn't already, comment out the var h line and then set the height manually:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tbc = document.getElementById("tblCont");
    //var h = Math.round((window.innerHeight)-(70))+"px";
    tbc.style.height = "50px";
</script>
```

Second, try alerting out the h variable instead of setting the height:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tbc = document.getElementById("tblCont");
    var h = Math.round((window.innerHeight)-(70))+"px";
    alert(h);
    //tbc.style.height = "50px";
</script>
```

My guess is that the problem is with how h is getting set, which is then killing anything after it.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you look at a third party Grid solution such as the [Data Grid](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid) from the [Dojo toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/).
From experience, I can say that building a highly-functional data grid from scratch in DHTML is very difficult and making it cross browser compatible is just not fun.